# javascript function to hide and show a hyperlink depending upon the mobile browser?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a mobile website which targets all the mobile platforms(i-phone, i-pad,Blackberry,android e.t.c).

```
 <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
     <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home"></a>
     <div id="title">Venue Information</div></div>
```

Above written code is a common small piece of code for the header for the whole website.
As mentioned above, I'm wondering if it is possible to hide the Middle line that is a Button icon(hyperlink to index.html) if it is running on I-Phone and Blackberry and show the same if any other platform( android, desktop e.t.c)

Any code-snippet will highly be appreciated.

mrana....

Comment: i'm not an expert in mobile support but i think the navigator object could help (e.g. `window.navigator.platform`)

Comment: Why would you exactly do that? Why Iphone and Blackberry? Maybe there is a better solution for you if you tell us why. Browser/platform sniffing is not the best idea in most cases.

Comment: Actually we are creating mobile app for I-phone , Blackberry and rest of mobile platforms/desktop (WEB-Version). So my task is to create mobile pages for that app. And we use these pages on each platform. So my problem is if i use these pages on Blackberry and iphone then there is always a hyperlink to index.html on every page header and if user clicks on that he/she is directed to the web app from the native platform(BB, Iphone) which i don't want. Neither i can delete this as this is required in web app.

Comment: @bazmegakapa do you have any solution in your mind?

Comment: @mrana Please include this in your question (edit it). Next time you ask provide all the relevant info. You will get much better results.

Comment: @bazmegakapa if you have any solution then pls share that and i don't think this description is making any kinda difference here as the output is still BIG ZERO and basically this history description was not necessary, that's why i didn't explained that.

Comment: @mrana I think it does make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://plungjan.name/iphone_bb.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var supportedMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/iphone|blackberry|playbook/i);
    if (supportedMobile) {
         $("a[data-role='button']").html("You have a(n) "+supportedMobile);
         if (supportedMobile!="BlackBerry") $("a[data-role='button']").fadeOut('slow');
         else $("a[data-role='button']").hide(); // BB does not fade on my 5700
    }    
});
```

Comment: sorry once again not working. Have u checked this code yourself?

Comment: Yes I did. BB does not fade so now I hide instead. See updated [DEMO](http://plungjan.name/iphone_bb.html)

Comment: Tested on iPhone 4S and BB5700

Comment: Now its working :) Thank you very much not only for this code but showing such a great interest in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's a little piece of heaven for that specific type of question:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

**EDIT CAUSE OF FIRST COMMENT BELOW:**

Ok, so if you look at the jquery code example you can see:
navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);

and if you google that you get this:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

**EDIT 2: more visible code**

Use the following code to get your browser support:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/)
 ){
 // some code
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: cool site but not for the above question. The code on that site is not easily hackable to detect ONLY 2 of many

Comment: It's a more widely based answer so it's not overkill, it's just less specific and with the attached resources, it speaks to a wider audience

Comment: Now better. However he only wants iPhone and BB

Comment: I know, that's why I think your answer suits this specific person's question more than mine, whilst mine is overall more practical for people getting to this post through search engines.

Answer (score 0):

If the scenario fits, you could hide the link if the user's screen size is too small:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 .hideifsmall {display: none}
}
</style>

<a href="index.html" class="hideifsmall" data-role="button" data-icon="home"></a>
```